# Send SIGTERM to a suspended process

Tags: c, signals

I have 2 processes written in C, I'll call them *'parent'* and *'child'*.
Parent creates child and child enters a loop where it does some code, then raises `SIGSTOP`. If a certain condition is reached, the parent needs to send the child `SIGTERM`, otherwise `SIGCONT`.

How can I send it `SIGTERM` while it is suspended and get exactly my desired results? By simply sending it `SIGCONT` then `SIGTERM` I'm afraid the child will reach `SIGSTOP` before `SIGTERM` is sent, and I also think the 2 signals one after the other will interfere with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a process in a suspended state, it won't action any signals (other than `SIGKILL`) until it continues. A pending signal will be queued on the process.

So depending on your situation you will need to send either:

1. `SIGTERM` and then `SIGCONT`
2. `SIGCONT`

Of course this can be simplified to

```
if (condition) { send SIGTERM }
send SIGCONT
```